# Use a function built outside the class on an object in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, object, methods

I have a class

```
class List:

    def __init__(self,head,tail):
        self.head = head
        self.tail = tail

    def cons(self,item):
        return List(item,self)

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def display(self):
        s = "["
        first = True
        list = self
        while not list.isEmpty():
            if not first:
                s=s+","
            first = False
            s=s+str(list.head)
            list = list.tail
        s=s+"]"
        return s`
```

which creates a `List` object. I have a function (not sure if it works yet);

```
def sorted(list):
    sort = False
    i = 0
    while i < range(len(list))+1:
        if list[i] < list[i+1]:
            sort = True
            return sort 
        else:
            return sort
```

and I want to run this function on the `List` object without adding another method to the class. I know if this was in the class it would just be List.sorted() but how can I run this function on the object without it being the objects method?

`sorted(List)` doesn't seem to work either. Help please.

Comment: What do you mean _run this function on the object_?  If you mean, you want to be able to use `self`, just use `list`.

Comment: Yeah I don't think I've explained this properly but basically the List class creates an object called list. I want to find out if this list is sorted by running my sorted function on it. But when I call it by doing sorted(list) I get the error 'List' object is not iterable

Comment: How would you create a `List` of three items?

Answer (score -1):

Please, please, PLEASE: don't use `sorted` as a function name. There is a standard (built-in) function `sorted()` already, that returns a sorted version of an iterable.

Given that your code just checks to see if the List is in order, perhaps you could call it `in_order` or `ordered` or `is_ascending` instead?

That said, let's try to get your code working:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class List:
    def __init__(self, head:Node=None, tail:Node=None):
        self.head = tail if head is None else head
        self.tail = head if tail is None else tail

    def cons(self, node:Node):
        node.next = self.head
        return List(node, self.tail)

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head == None

    def display(self):
        return str(self)

    def __str__(self):
        result = "["
        first = True

        n = self.head
        while n is not None:
            if not first:
                result += ", "
            result += str(n)
            if n == self.tail:
                break
            n = n.next
            first = False

        result += "]"
        return result

    def ascendingp(self) -> bool:
        n = self.head
        last = None

        while last != self.tail:
            if last is not None and not last.data < n.data:
                return False
            last = n
            n = n.next

        return True

tests = (
    (1,2,3),
    (1,3,2),
    (),
)

for t in tests:
    last = None
    first = None
    for i in reversed(t):
        n = Node(data=i)
        first = n if first is None else first
        n.next = last
        last = n

    l = List(head=last, tail=first)
    print(str(l), "Ascending?", l.ascendingp())
```

Comment: Yes. Given that the question was tagged "python", and given that python 2 has been obsolete for 8 years now, it seems reasonable, don't you think?

Comment: The OP did not use the python-3 tag. Python 2.7 will be supported for four more years.  You should at least make very clear that your code will only work on Python-3.